# Problems with Netty openning / closing "zumbi" connections (channels)

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty 3.2.4 and and I am trying to debug my application to solve a bug, but I realized that after I start my app running with Netty, every 2 seconds I get a open/close connection (channel) from "nowhere".

I threw a new Exception to get the stack trace to discover where does it come from and I see a "DeadLockProofWorker$1" class running, according to the following stack trace.

Where does it come from? Why? Could it be avoided?

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.spcbrasil.commbroker.server.handler.CleanUpServerHandler.channelClosed(CleanUpServerHandler.java:26)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.channelClosed(SimpleChannelHandler.java:228)
    at org.spcbrasil.commbroker.server.handler.CommBrokerServiceHandler.channelClosed(CommBrokerServiceHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.channelClosed(SimpleChannelHandler.java:228)
    at org.spcbrasil.commbroker.server.handler.LogServerHandler.channelClosed(LogServerHandler.java:145)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.channelClosed(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:208)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:98)
    at org.spcbrasil.commbroker.server.handler.HandshakeStopServerHandler.handleUpstream(HandshakeStopServerHandler.java:28)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.channelClosed(SimpleChannelHandler.java:228)
    at org.spcbrasil.commbroker.server.handler.HandshakeServerHandler.channelClosed(HandshakeServerHandler.java:107)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:118)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:66)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:404)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:593)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:355)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking from this:

```
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:593)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:355)
```

The remote peer closed the connection.  Does your remote peer use half-closed connection?  Netty does not support half-closed connection, and thus the connection will be closed if the remote peer closed only half of the connection.